# Matching the same variable amount multiple times in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have some tokens that look like `{{{this}}}` and some tokens that look like `{{this}}` (where `this` is *anything*). I want to match both types of tokens with one regular expression. I came up with the following:

```
\{{2,3}[^\{\}]+\}{2,3}
```

However, that also matches tokens like `{{this}}}` and `{{{this}}`. So I made the following:

```
(?:\{{3}[^\{\}]+\}{3})|(?:\{{2}[^\{\}]+\}{2})
```

That works (will perform matches such as **{**`{{this}}`), but it's much longer. Is there any way to get the result of the second regular expression with the compactness of the first regular expression? In other words, say that because two (or three) brackets were matched at the beginning, I want to match an equal number of closing brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just wait for someone else to prove me wrong, but I believe that your 2nd example is the best you can do.  (This is similar to tag matching with regular expressions in HTML or XML, where using something like XPath is typically a better bet.)